# Is there a way to go to checkout page after customer clicks add to cart (BigCartel Netizen Theme)

Tags: html, css

`<button class="button add-to-cart-button" name="submit" type="submit" title="Add to Cart" data-adding-text="Adding..." data-added-text="Added!" data-add-title="Add to Cart" data-sold-title="Sold out"{% if product.has_default_option %}{% else %}disabled="disabled"{% endif %}>Add to Cart</button>`

That is the code above for the add to cart button! After being clicked it adds items to cart but does not open the cart page. However, I would like to take the customer one step further to  the checkout page once they click add to cart (with their selection of course).

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Could you show us what is in the `<form>` opening tag?

Comment: <form method="post" class="product-form {% if theme.show_sold_out_product_options %}show-sold-out{% else %}hide-sold-out{% endif %}" action="/cart" accept-charset="utf8">

This is what I tried for it to go to cart but no luck!